# How to fill array of boolean values on checkbox change event?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, checkbox

What I would like to do is, filling the answers array with boolean values.My checkboxes are populated dynamically but there will be only four of them. If checkbox is unchecked then its value should be false and if checked it should be true.Values should correspond to array index, I mean if first checkbox is switched then only answers[0] should change, if second checkbox is changed then  answers[1] and so on..

Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-thompson-7rthy?file=/src/App.js

I would also appreciate if you can help me setting the checked value as well.

In the end I am setting this values to the context store to be send to server in the end.

```
const Quiz1 = (props) => {
      const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([false, false, false, false]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
     setAnswers([...answers, e.target.checked]);
     setQuizState({ id: 0, question_id: question.question_id, answer: [answers] });
  };
    return (
    {question?.options?.map((option, i) => { 
       <Checkbox
         id={i}
         name={option}
         checked={WHAT TO PUT HERE?}
         onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />}
 )
}
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of you code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: here you go
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-thompson-7rthy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a shallow copy of the state and change its value. Here's the simple sample of the thing which you want:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Quiz1 = (props) => {
  const question = {
    options: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
  };

  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([false, false, false, false]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(answers);
  }, [answers]);

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    let copy = [...answers];
    let current = copy[i];
    current = e.target.checked;
    copy[i] = current;
    setAnswers(copy);
  };
  return question?.options?.map((option, i) => {
    return (
      <>
        <label>{option}</label>
        <input
          aria-label={option}
          id={i}
          name={option}
          checked={answers[i]}
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
        />
      </>
    );
  });
};
export default function App() {
  return <Quiz1 />;
}
```

[image: Edit lingering-resonance-7mycm]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you can just use the index of your map function to use the correct answer index.

`checked={answer[i]}`

Setting `setAnswers([...answers, e.target.checked])` will append the new new event value to your answer array. Instead you should override the answer value.

`answer[i] = e.target.value`

Comment: You are right about the first part, I think checked value can be determined like that. But assigning target value to answer[i] is not working because it is a React state I guess.

Comment: You can definitely do it like this way. Because its an array (reference type) you can update the values like this.It wil not update using the useState() though, then you should add in the useEffect(() ,[answer]) . Shallow copy actually does the same solution as i guest